# Integrating the area of a quarter-circle

Tags: calculus, integration

> $A=\int_0^r\sqrt{r^2-x^2}\,dx$ is the area of a quarter-circle. Show why, with a graph and thin rectangles. Calculate this integral by substituting $x=r\sin\theta$ and $\,dx = r\cos\theta\,d\theta$.

As shown below, the area can be seen as a collection of thin horizontal strips $\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$, $0 \le x \le r$.

[image: Quarter-circle]

By substituting $x=r\sin\theta$ and $dx = r\cos\theta\,d\theta$, we have
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^r\sqrt{r^2-x^2}\,dx&=\int_0^rr^2\cos^2\theta\,d\theta\\
&=r^2\left(\frac14\sin(2\theta)+\frac12\theta\right)|_0^r\\
&=\frac14r^2\sin(2r)+\frac12r^3\\
\end{align}$$

Why did we not get the area $\frac14\pi r^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do the substitution $x = r \sin \theta$, the limits of integration of your integral must change as well. That is,

when $x = 0 $, then $\sin \theta = 0 \implies \theta = 0$

when $x = r$, then $\sin \theta =1 \implies \theta = \frac{ \pi }{2} $